# How to set fsolve maximum iteration count in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, iteration

i have a problem with fsolve. I need to set MaxFunEvals, but it doesn't work now. When I call fsolve by this:

```
[X,fval]= fsolve(@(Q) fkinf(L1,L2,L3,L4,P,Q), [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]);
```

i get a message:

```
Warning: Trust-region-dogleg algorithm of FSOLVE cannot handle non-square 
systems; using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm instead. 
  In fsolve at 285
  In fkin at 11
```

and after a minute or so

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

fsolve stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunEvals = 1800 (the default value).
```

This message persist if I try to change it before calling fsolve by:

```
optimoptions('fsolve','MaxFunEvals',100)
```

or

```
optimoptions('fsolve','MaxFunEvals',100,'Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt')
```

I get a good result, but the computing time is too long. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Are you actually passing the output from `optimoptions` in to `fsolve`? Your code makes it look like you're not.

Comment: @horchler Yeah that's it, I thought I can call optimoptions anytime during operation. Couldn't figure it out, thank you.